# DC-AC converter with GaN in Ltspice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, inverter, gan

I'm simulating a DC-AC SPWM converter in Ltspice with a GaN E-HEMT (https://gansystems.com/gan-transistors/gs66516b/) but I'm having problems because I get the error for the time step to small. This is the circuit:
[image]

and this is the netlist:

```
    * C:\Users\Latini1\Desktop\CONVERTITORE\Conv_finale.asc
    V1 UE 0 400
    XX9 Vref PWM pwm params: f=400k Vhigh=1 Vlow=0
    R1 N007 UA 40
    L1 N007 UB 300µ
    A1 PWM 0 0 0 0 N021 0 0 BUF tau=5n
    A2 PWM 0 0 0 0 0 N018 0 BUF tau=5n
    V2 Vref 0 SINE(0.5 0.45 50)
    B1 N003 N008 V=(V(s1)*6)
    B2 N012 N016 V=(V(S3)*6)
    B3 N006 N009 V=(V(s3)*6)
    B4 N015 N017 V=(V(S1)*6)
    RG1 N004 N003 20
    RG2 N013 N012 20
    RG3 N006 N005 20
    RG4 N015 N014 20
    A3 0 N018 0 0 0 N020 N019 0 AND td=50n
    A4 0 N018 0 N019 0 0 S1 0 AND tripdt=5n
    A5 0 N020 0 N021 0 0 S3 0 AND tripdt=5n
    C1 N007 UA 100µ
    D5 N004 N002 Dideal
    D6 N013 N010 Dideal
    D7 N005 N001 Dideal
    D8 N014 N011 Dideal
    R2 N002 N003 5
    R3 N010 N012 5
    R4 N006 N001 5
    R5 N015 N011 5
    XU1 N004 UE UA N008 NC_11 0 GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1
    XU2 N013 UA 0 N016 NC_12 0 GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1
    XU3 N005 UE UB N009 NC_13 0 GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1
    XU4 N014 UB 0 N017 NC_14 0 GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1

    * block symbol definitions
    .subckt pwm Vin PWM
    V1 Vtri 0 PULSE({Vlow} {Vhigh-Vlow} 0 {1/(2*f)} {1/(2*f)} {1/(100*f)} {1/f})
    A1 Vin Vtri 0 0 0 0 N001 0 SCHMITT Vt=0.0001 Vh=0.0001 Td=5n
    G1 0 PWM N001 0 1
    R1 PWM 0 1
    C1 PWM 0 1f
    .param f=400k
    .param Vhigh=1
    .param Vlow=0
    .ends pwm

    .model D D
    .lib C:\Users\Latini1\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.dio
    .tran 0 0.03 0.01
    .param D_Vto=0
    .param D_ron=0.1m
    .model Dideal D(Vfwd={D_Vto} Ron={D_ron})
    .option ITL1=500
    .option ITL2=500
    .option ITL4=500
    .option RELTOL=0.01
    .option ABSTOL=1E-09
    .option CHGTOL=1E-12
    .option VNTOL=1E-6
    .option GMIN=1E-15
    .option TRTOL=1
    .option noopiter
    .option gminsteps=0
    .option topologycheck=0
    .lib GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1.lib
    .backanno
    .end
```

I found .option commands on the site of the device and I want to test the converter for a load frequency of 50 Hz and 400 kHz frequency commutation. Output signals of the pwm generator are good because I've tested them. What you suggest to do? After this simulation I want to try to change some parameters (like Vin Rgate Vgate dead time or considerind the Tj) and study the results. Someone has already worked with this kind of transistor? Thanks a lot in advance.

UPDATE

@a concerned citizen @winny

I tried to change something using your comments: this is the new circuit
[image]

And this is the problem:in green there is the Vgs of the first transistor and in blu the Vgs of the second [image]

The recomanded Vgs in the datasheet is 0 to 6V. I separeted the Rg on and off but it does't works.
This is the schematic maybe it can help (hope I made it right this time):

`Version 4
SHEET 1 1320 1148
WIRE -880 48 -976 48
WIRE -464 48 -880 48
WIRE 256 48 -464 48
WIRE 432 64 400 64
WIRE -880 80 -880 48
WIRE -608 96 -640 96
WIRE -464 96 -464 48
WIRE 256 96 256 48
WIRE -976 112 -976 48
WIRE -768 176 -832 176
WIRE -720 176 -720 96
WIRE -720 176 -768 176
WIRE -672 176 -720 176
WIRE -544 176 -544 96
WIRE -544 176 -592 176
WIRE -528 176 -544 176
WIRE 336 176 336 64
WIRE 336 176 320 176
WIRE 384 176 336 176
WIRE 512 176 512 64
WIRE 512 176 464 176
WIRE 624 176 512 176
WIRE 720 176 624 176
WIRE -880 192 -912 192
WIRE 816 192 768 192
WIRE -464 240 -464 192
WIRE -272 240 -272 208
WIRE -272 240 -464 240
WIRE -224 240 -272 240
WIRE -192 240 -224 240
WIRE -96 240 -112 240
WIRE -64 240 -96 240
WIRE 80 240 80 208
WIRE 80 240 16 240
WIRE 256 240 256 192
WIRE 256 240 80 240
WIRE -976 256 -976 192
WIRE -768 256 -832 256
WIRE -512 256 -512 208
WIRE -512 256 -768 256
WIRE 304 256 304 208
WIRE 624 256 304 256
WIRE 720 256 624 256
WIRE -608 304 -640 304
WIRE -464 304 -464 240
WIRE 256 304 256 240
WIRE 432 304 400 304
WIRE -224 336 -224 240
WIRE -192 336 -224 336
WIRE -96 336 -96 240
WIRE -96 336 -128 336
WIRE -768 384 -832 384
WIRE -720 384 -720 304
WIRE -720 384 -768 384
WIRE -672 384 -720 384
WIRE -544 384 -544 304
WIRE -544 384 -592 384
WIRE -528 384 -544 384
WIRE 336 384 336 304
WIRE 336 384 320 384
WIRE 400 384 336 384
WIRE 512 384 512 304
WIRE 512 384 480 384
WIRE 624 384 512 384
WIRE 720 384 624 384
WIRE -880 400 -912 400
WIRE 816 400 768 400
WIRE 304 464 304 416
WIRE 624 464 304 464
WIRE 720 464 624 464
WIRE -832 480 -832 464
WIRE -768 480 -768 464
WIRE -768 480 -832 480
WIRE -512 480 -512 416
WIRE -512 480 -768 480
WIRE -464 480 -464 400
WIRE 256 480 256 400
WIRE 0 560 -192 560
WIRE 96 560 64 560
WIRE 176 560 96 560
WIRE -752 592 -1120 592
WIRE -592 592 -688 592
WIRE -544 592 -592 592
WIRE -448 592 -544 592
WIRE -384 592 -448 592
WIRE -320 592 -384 592
WIRE -288 592 -320 592
WIRE -192 592 -192 560
WIRE -192 592 -224 592
WIRE -144 592 -192 592
WIRE 0 592 -80 592
WIRE 96 592 96 560
WIRE 176 592 96 592
WIRE -752 624 -944 624
WIRE -544 624 -544 592
WIRE -448 624 -448 592
WIRE -384 624 -384 592
WIRE -48 624 -80 624
WIRE -592 640 -592 592
WIRE -944 656 -944 624
WIRE -320 656 -320 592
WIRE -288 656 -320 656
WIRE -192 656 -224 656
WIRE -48 656 -48 624
WIRE 0 656 -48 656
WIRE 96 656 64 656
WIRE 176 656 96 656
WIRE -1120 688 -1120 672
WIRE -192 688 -192 656
WIRE 0 688 -192 688
WIRE 96 688 96 656
WIRE 176 688 96 688
WIRE -944 768 -944 736
WIRE -592 768 -592 688
WIRE -544 768 -544 704
WIRE -448 768 -448 704
WIRE -384 768 -384 688
FLAG -880 80 UE
FLAG -1120 688 0
FLAG -272 208 UA
FLAG 80 208 UB
FLAG -1120 592 Vref
FLAG 256 480 0
FLAG -464 480 0
FLAG 176 560 S4
FLAG 176 592 S1
FLAG 176 656 S2
FLAG 176 688 S3
FLAG -976 256 0
FLAG 768 240 0
FLAG 768 448 0
FLAG -880 240 0
FLAG -880 448 0
FLAG -912 192 S1
FLAG -912 400 S2
FLAG 816 192 S3
FLAG 816 400 S4
FLAG -416 128 0
FLAG -416 336 0
FLAG 208 128 0
FLAG 208 336 0
FLAG -944 768 0
FLAG -592 768 0
FLAG -544 768 0
FLAG -448 768 0
FLAG -384 768 0
SYMBOL voltage -976 96 R0
WINDOW 3 -38 26 VLeft 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 400
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.1 Cpar=1m
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL res -96 224 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 40
SYMBOL ind -80 256 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 300µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=10m Rpar=100k
SYMBOL Digital\\inv -288 592 R0
WINDOW 3 -27 113 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tau=5n
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\buf1 -288 528 R0
WINDOW 0 8 31 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -18 4 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMATTR Value tau=5n
SYMBOL voltage -1120 576 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -81 156 Left 2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0.5 0.45 50)
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL res -576 160 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RG1
SYMATTR Value 30
SYMBOL res -576 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RG2
SYMATTR Value 30
SYMBOL res 480 160 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RG3
SYMATTR Value 30
SYMBOL res 496 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RG4
SYMATTR Value 30
SYMBOL Digital\\and -112 544 R0
WINDOW 3 -32 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value td=50n
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\and 32 512 R0
WINDOW 3 -40 4 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=5n
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\and 32 608 R0
WINDOW 3 -34 111 Left 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=5n
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL cap -128 320 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=10m
SYMBOL diode -544 80 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMATTR Value Dideal
SYMBOL diode -544 288 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value Dideal
SYMBOL diode 336 80 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D7
SYMATTR Value Dideal
SYMBOL diode 336 320 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMATTR Value Dideal
SYMBOL res -624 80 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res -624 288 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 528 48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 528 288 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g -832 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName G1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g -832 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName G2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 720 160 M0
SYMATTR InstName G3
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL g 720 368 M0
SYMATTR InstName G4
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res -784 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 6
SYMBOL res -784 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 6
SYMBOL res 608 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 6
SYMBOL res 608 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 6
SYMBOL GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1 -512 144 R0
WINDOW 3 281 -72 Center 2
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1 -512 352 R0
WINDOW 3 252 87 Center 2
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1 304 144 M0
WINDOW 3 297 -42 Center 2
SYMATTR InstName U3
SYMBOL GaN_LTspice_GS66516B_L3V4P1 304 352 M0
WINDOW 3 239 111 Center 2
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMBOL voltage -944 640 R0
WINDOW 3 -78 188 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PULSE({Vlow} {Vhigh-Vlow} 0 {1/(2*f)} {1/(2*f)} {1/(100*f)} {1/f})
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL Digital\\diffschmitt -752 544 R0
WINDOW 3 -39 -19 Left 2
SYMATTR Value Vt=0.0001 Vh=0.0001 Td=5n
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL g -544 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName G5
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res -464 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL cap -400 624 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 1f
TEXT 112 968 Left 2 !.tran 0.03
TEXT 112 904 Left 2 !.param D_Vto=0\n.param D_ron=0.1m
TEXT 112 872 Left 2 !.model Dideal D(Vfwd={D_Vto} Ron={D_ron} Epsilon={10m} RevEpsilon={10m})
TEXT 512 528 Left 2 !.option ITL1=500\n.option ITL2=500\n.option ITL4=500\n.option RELTOL=0.01\n.option ABSTOL=1E-09\n.option CHGTOL=1E-12\n.option VNTOL=1E-6\n.option GMIN=1E-15\n.option TRTOL=1\n.option noopiter\n.option gminsteps=0\n.option topologycheck=0
TEXT -728 864 Left 2 !.param f=400k\n.param Vhigh=1\n.param Vlow=0`

Comment: Try alternate solver. Does it work with ideal transistors or switches?

Comment: @winny I'm using ltspice model of transistor provided by the manufacturer. I tried also the alternate solver but nothing changes: the simulation is very slow in some points and doesn't converge

Comment: Yes, but what if you use any other transistor or an ideal switch? Do you get any difference?

Comment: Yes it works with ideal transistor. I think the problem is that there are shortcircuits when a transistor is on and the other transistor on the same bridge turns on without command because the Vgs has some peaks and rises above the threshold voltage of 1.1V. I have used two different resistances for turn on and turn off (20 and 5 ohms) but if I use Vgs fro 0 to 6V it is not enough. What can I do?

Comment: Try to help out the solver by inserting mohm of series resistance, megaohm of bleeder and pF capacitance across it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some of these, for start:

- Avoid behavioural sources, just use VCVS (`E`) with `6` as gain. Better yet, use VCCS (`G`) with a unity gain and `6 Ohms` terminating resistance, since voltage sources off the ground are not as convergence-friendly as their current counterparts.
- No need to ground unused A-devices pins, they are internally grounded if not used. It's also a possible cause for wrong results (see the manual at `LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. Special Functions`, among the first paragraphs).
- Add parasitics as helpers: to the main supply (e.g. `Rser=0.1 Cpar=1m`), capacitors (e.g. `Rser=10m`), inductors (e.g. `Rser=10m Rpar=100k`).
- If you're going to use the default, ideal diode, the biggest service you can do to yourself is to set `epsilon` (and `revepsilon`) to something in the range `10m...100m`. Else, since you're already going through the trouble of simulating real-life elements, you may as well select a model from the database, or external sources.
- Not lastly, your copy-pasted code is useless because you pasted the *netlist*, as opposed to the *schematic* (the `.asc` file). Even then, without the custom library/-ies and symbols (which I can get from your link), it still could be useless -- but something to remember when sending schematics to others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment and sorry for the wrong netlist. I'll try with your advices but I have a question: if i want a Vgs in a range for example of -2V/+6V how can I realize it with VCCS?